# How much edges you need to add to bipartite graph to make coloring = 8

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Please I need to find answer to this question, how much edges we need to add to bipartite graph $K_{4,4}$ to make graph coloring = 8 ? And why?

Comment: Please, use the right terms: "chromatic number = 8" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if there were two non-adjacent vertices, then we could color them using the same color, and color the rest of the vertices with six other (distinct) colors, so in this case the chromatic number would be at most seven. Thus we need to add an edge between every non-adjacent pair of vertices, which makes $8 \cdot 7 / 2 - 4 \cdot 4 = 12$ edges.